# Is possible opening stdin after close(0)?

Tags: c, linux, io

I have one question,studying standard I/O.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main(){
    void *mem = malloc(0x80);
    close(0)
     /*
      something code (solution)
   */
    read(0,mem,0x80);
    }
```

with above code, Is possible opening stdin ?
before ask question on stackoverflow, i thought that open('/dev/tty'); .
but it not seem to  completely open stdin. 
i hope that do not use dup()

Comment: Imagine that `stdin_fileno` is actually the FD of a file on disk, and it's the last such FD. Once you close it, the file may be deleted. So you definitely have no way in principle to restore a closed FD that points to the same file. You could reopen FD 0 to a *new* file of course.

Comment: @KerrekSB So, how to create stdin at the program start ?

Comment: @오우진: What is your reason to avoid `dup` or `dup2` ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i want to know actual principle of creating stdin.

Comment: @오우진: You don't. The FDs come already open. The parent process usually provides them.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, the ideal way to achieve this would be

- use `dup()` to create a backup `fd`.
- `close()` the `stdin`.
- perform the *operations*
- restore `stdin` using the `dup2()` and passing the previous backup `fd`.

Comment: Isn't there another way?  If possible , It would be good to do not use dup()